# How can I create controls of form by For loop? (ionic2,3)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

ts file:

```
    this.addAdvertise = this.formBuilder.group({
      input1: [''],
      input2: [''],
      .
      .
      .
      inputN: [''],
      desc:  ['']
    });
```

count of inputs comes from length of array, and array gets from server.

can I use for loop to create input controls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a simple for-loop:

```
let group = {};

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    group[`input${i+1}`] = [..];
}

this.addAdvertise = this.formBuilder.group(group);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have use reactive forms and forms module in ionic 2 or 3,

Add this code in your app.module.ts file,

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Add this code in your component file,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    name:string;
    dynamicForm:any = FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){ 

    this.dynamicForm = this.fb.group({
      properties: this.fb.array([])
    });
   }

  addProperty() {
    for(var i=1; i<=1; i++) {
      <FormArray>this.dynamicForm.get('properties').push(new FormControl());
    }
  }

}
```

Add this code in your HTML file,

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

 <button (click)="addProperty()">Add Property</button>
    <form [formGroup]="dynamicForm">
    <div formArrayName="properties">
      <div *ngFor="let prop of dynamicForm.get('properties').controls; let i = index " >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <pre>{{dynamicForm.value | json }}</pre>


</ion-content>
```

Thanks,